# Errores al hacer build con GX 18 ( Domain y GxFullTextSearchReindexer )

Tags: genexus

Tengo una KB que funciona correctamente en GX 17U11 pero genera errores al hacer un build en GX18. Estoy usando Java y Postgresql.

En un procedimiento que tiene una variable que es de tipo Domain, me surge este error:

```
*****.java:411: error: cannot find symbol
     AV16colMes = com.*****.gxdomainmes.getValues() ;
  symbol:   class gxdomainmes
```

Además en algunas transacciones me surge este error:

```
GxFullTextSearchReindexer.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
      obj = new com.*******.******(remoteHandle);
  symbol:   class **********
```

Intenté hacer build varias veces en GX 18 (intenté con U1 y U2).

Alguna idea do cómo solucionarlos?